# If the radius of convergence of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^n$ is 6, what is the radius of convergence of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^{\frac{n}{2}}$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> If the radius of convergence of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^n$ is 6, what is the radius of convergence of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^{\frac{n}{2}}$?

**My Attempt:**

We know that:

$$\frac{a_{n+1}x^{n+1}}{a_n x^n}<1$$

$$\implies \frac{a_{n+1}x}{a_n}<1 \implies \frac{6a_{n+1}}{a_n}<1$$

Now we have to find:

$$\frac{a_{n+1}x^{(n+1)/2}}{a_n x^{n/2}}<1$$

$$\frac{a_{n+1}x^{n/2}}{a_n}<1$$

**Now, how to find the radius of convergence in this?
How do we combine these two to find the radius of convergence?**

**This is confusing**

Comment: There is a typo in the last inequality, it should be $x^{1/2}$ not $x^{n/2}$.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint.** Consider that
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^{\frac{n}{2}}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n t^{n}
$$ with

> $$x^{1/2}=t.$$

On the right hand side, the series is convergent for $|t|<6$, giving 
$$
|x^{1/2}|<6
$$ or
$$
|x|<36.
$$ Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yes :) OH I see thanks alot.

Comment: @M.S.E You are welcome.

Comment: If we are sticking to real numbers, the most you can say is the series converges for $0\le x < 36.$ (So there's no "radius" of convergence actually.)